# making a USB copy of custom installation media served to clients via PXE

Tags: pxe-boot

I have searched for someone asking this question on here before and found two that seemed similar to this. One was not answered and seemed abandoned. The other hinted that it might be possible by editing initrd and mentioned that there was no canned utility as this task is not trivial. In regards to the first question,  I don't think the person had permission to do this on his network as this was the last question that was asked of the OP. I have full permission to do as I please on this network as it belongs to me. As for the second question, the answer was incomplete and basically amounted to "there's no app to do this for you and doing it yourself is hard".

I have a Linux deployment server and use PXE to deploy customized Linux installs to clients. The installations are customized via pressed files and kickstart files to create the final installed client image. I also have an installation image that was customized by way of chroot into squashfs to apt install software.

I would like to know if there is a way for me to include a choice in the PXE menu to allow for someone to insert a USB drive and make a copy of the installer media that's being offered up by the PXE server.

The only way that I can think of achieving this is by compiling an ISO of all the separate parts and files, hosting them on the server, providing a menu item to select which then boots into a minimal Linux instance that then pulls and dd's the ISO to USB media.

I would like to not have to host ISO's on the server due to memory constraints and am wondering if there are any other options for me that would allow me to accomplish this task using the setup that is already there.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

PXE establishes a connection via TFTP to the server to download the boot code.

You would just need a lightweight Linux such as ISOLinux as a boot selection. Use shell scripting to create a boot menu for ISOLinux, for formatting/partitioning the USB sticks and then loading the boot image onto the USB stick from the PXE TFTP server.

TFTP does not offer a way to list directory contents, but you could create a txt/cfg file on the server with the list of available boot images, and then your menu system looks for this file with TFTP, to create the menu list of USB sticks it can provide.